# Entity Framework 5 Lost its Connection String

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-5

I have used EF5 for my project and I encrypted my connection string in project's `web.config` file.

And I replaced the constructor of `Entities` like this:

```
public PEntities()
       // : base("name=PaypalEntities")
       : base(Cryptography.DecryptConnectionString())
{
}
```

But when I want to update my database model with EF wizard, it asks to me for a new connection string and credentials and replaces my connection string in my config file with this. So my project doesn't run properly.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd strongly encourage you to have the Entity framework model in a **separate project**. If you do that, the project can have its own connection string that points to your reference database (the one you use for making changes as and when necessary). Thus, the running assembly, whether it be a web project or anything else, will just refer to the model project and can have its own connection string.

Answer (score 0):

Yes...
The Solution is, Create a Partial class with same namespace and write the method into it.
Now whenever you update database or edmx file you will find it's default constructor. just delete it.

refer this 
http://forums.asp.net/post/4722699.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try to uncheck the "Save entity connection settings" checkbox:

[image]